# Summary table for aggregate values in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, aggregate

I have a data frame like below

```
    ID        VALUE   GROUP   MODEL
1     id_1   17.6100597 Group A Model B
2    id_10 6814.7109375 Group A Model B
3   id_100   26.5990372 Group C Model F
4  id_1000    0.0000000 Group B Model D
5   id_101  486.4001160 Group C Model C
6   id_102  108.9007416 Group C Model C
7   id_103    1.0070915 Group B Model F
8   id_104    0.5426522 Group B Model F
9   id_105    1.1137601 Group C Model C
10  id_106    0.2867465 Group C Model C
```

and I would like to create a summary table with the aggregate values based on Groups and Models. So for every group the aggregates of each models and a further row with the total for that group. Like

```
# Groups    Models    Aggregates
# Group A   Model A   aggAA
# Group A   Model B   aggAB
# Group A   Total A   aggA
# Group B   Model A   aggBA
# Group B   Model B   aggBB
# Group B   Model C   aggBC
# Group B   Total B   aggB
```

I create this script to do that

```
dat <- read.csv2("data.csv")

dat$GROUP <- factor(dat$GROUP)
groupnames <- levels(dat$GROUP)

resume <- NULL
for (group in groupnames) {
  dat1 <- dat1[dat1$GROUP == group,]

  aggdat1 <- aggregate(dat1[,"VALUE"],list(dat1[,"MODEL"]),FUN=sum)
  colnames(aggdat1) <- c("MODEL", "VALUE")

  resumegroup <- rbind(aggdat1,c(" ",colSums(aggdat1[-1])))
  resumegroup <- cbind("GROUP"=group,resumegroup)

  resume <- rbind(resume,resumegroup)
}

resume
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I got a weird error message after the subset command, already for the first iteration (Group A) when it's clear that must be with some rows.

> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
>
> Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
>     no rows to aggregate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(GROUP,MODEL) %>% summarise(sum = sum(VALUE))
```

or in good old `R`:

```
aggregate(a$VALUE , by = list( a$GROUP , a$MODEL )  , FUN = sum)
```

Comment: Damn! yes, but there's not way to do without that library? and adding also the total?

Comment: yep, the sum of `VALUE` of every group, as final row. I'd better take the second but it mixes up the `GROUP` and bases the ordering on the `MODEL`

Comment: `a %>% group_by(GROUP,MODEL) %>% summarise(sum = sum(VALUE)) %>% group_by(GROUP) %>% mutate(group.sum = sum(sum) )`

Comment: Ok, you deserve the tick! :) I'll try to get exactly what I want starting from this. thanks!